# how to switch between window and pop_up window in selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

> I have to extract the links which is shown in picture two. for that
> first I have to click on each row of table( see picture one) ,
> clicking to this will open a pop window which is having a tab in it
> called link ( see picture two ) and then I have to extract that link
> from there.

[image]

[image]

I am trying to learn web scraping , I appreciate your help. website link [enter link description here](https://www.ungm.org/Public/Notice)
please note while loading the new table data tow it sends a new post request to the server and we have to go to all the table rows

Comment: What did your code tried so far ? any exception ?

Comment: @NarendraR , Actually I didn't get any idea how to start it. the pages loads the table dynamically , and i have to load all the tables and then click to each row and handle the new pop-up windows and extracting the link value , made me so confused.

Comment: Loop throw all the element you want to perform click, Check whether its a simple model popup or a different window and locate element accordingly and then do what you want to achieve and close the popup

Comment: If its a simple model popup then no need to do anything additional. you will be able to handle this in ordinary way.

Comment: NaredraR, the tables loads dynamically and while loading each time it sends new post request to the server, https://www.ungm.org/Public/Notice , I got some lines of code which loads all the tables and extracting the data using Beatifulsoup, but that does not help me because while loading the table i have to get the links highlighted in picture as well.  it would be my pleasure if you please help me with the code and then I will try to learn. thank you